# How to execute a job immediately using Laravel Queue

Tags: php, priority-queue, laravel-5.1

I have a sign up form which sends an email notification to the user email and I used Laravel Queue for all my background process (e.g. Mail::queue...).

My question is, say I have a 20 queued jobs in my table. And I always want to prioritize all email invitations first, I don't want it to wait. Is this possible? I still want to use the queue principle though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup multiple queues. For example one for background jobs with low priorities and one for email with a high priority.

See this link from the Laravel documentation regarding assign jobs to specific queues. [Pushing Jobs Onto The Queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue). Look into 'Specifying The Queue For A Job'.

After you have done setting this up you can assigning priorities to the queues. See the following link to the Laravel documentation. [Running The Queue Listener](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener). Look into 'Queue Priorities'.

Quote from Laravel documentation:

> In this example, jobs on the high queue will always be processed before moving onto jobs from the low queue.

Comment: i did what you suggest. But I cant get it to work. I added a new connection named database-high and made my email sending used it. But it doesnt get to process. I addded a --queue=database-high,database in my queue:listen in my supervisord setting

Comment: ignore my comment, i got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sync dispatching to execute job immediately if don't want to queue jobs.

From Docs - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues.
Synchronous Dispatching
If you would like to dispatch a job immediately (synchronously), you may use the dispatchSync method. When using this method, the job will not be queued and will be executed immediately within the current process:

```
ProcessPodcast::dispatchSync($podcast);
```

Having multiple queues for different kind of workflows is a way to prioritise work and execute asynchronously but it won't be immediate since those queues will be having multiple jobs pending at some point. Synchronous dispatching isn't recommended for a complex job work as it will block request and thread.